# Android: How to manage images (existing vs non existing) in the project

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-sdcard, android-image

The title seems ambigious but my goal is simple to understand.

- I have a certain number of images in my project under res/drawable-hdpi.
- In my app, I am geting a list of names from the server and I am saving them in the local databse.
- Each name corresponds to the name of the image with ".png" at the end.
- I am using the Galery and the user could choose one of the names from the database by clicking on his corresponding image.

Everything is fine until here.

But now, lets say that a new name will be added on the server side, so the image will not be in the application. In this case I have to update my app and put the right image inside.

In order to avoid that the user sees a "black -image" in the galery (because the image does not exists), I would like to create this image with android.

I am actually able to catch if the image does not exists in the project and to create a new one (white background with the name in the middle).

Now, the problem is how and where to store this new image. Apparently, it is not possible to store this in res/drawable folder. So, where and how to store?

Here is the part of the code where I am creating the new image:

```
if (imageId == 0)
            {
                Bitmap journal_template = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.journals_template).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(journal_template);

                Paint myPaint = new Paint();
                myPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                myPaint.setTextSize(25);

                String journal_name = publicJournalsNameSystem.get(i).toLowerCase(); 

                Paint textPaint = new Paint();
                textPaint.setARGB(200, 254, 0, 0);
                textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);

                int xPos = (myCanvas.getWidth() / 2);
                int yPos = (int) ((myCanvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent()) / 2)) ;

                myCanvas.drawText("Your text", xPos, yPos, myPaint);

                try {
                       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/journals_"+journal_name+".png");
                       journal_template.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Comment: You either save the files Internally if they're small or externally if they're large.  Keep track of their URIs either through a `ContentProvider` or private `SharedPreferences` or `SQL Database`.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: @DeeV, It seems interesting to save the file internaly: those are a couple of small images (220px x 70px) so non consuming in which concerns the size. Now, how to phisicaly save those files internaly? Could you give me some details please? I am trying to use FileOutputStream but don't know where to store them, which url to use.

Comment: That link has examples on how to store it both externally (SD card) and internally.  This link provides a good example on how to download the image itself from your web server.
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/store-imagesfiles-database

Comment: @DeeV, thank you, I will try t o explore this option and let you know in a couple of hours if everything was fine. If so, it will be nice to givve an answer so I will have the possibility to accept.

Comment: @DeeV, It works as a charm, thank you. Could you please answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use images from a web server, you need to first download the image on to the device then store it.

[Here is a good example of how to download the image.](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/store-imagesfiles-database)

[The developer website has methods on how to store data to the device.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)  You will either want to store it internally or (more preferably) externally to the SD card.  It would be recommended that you first check if the SD card is mounted on the device and usable. Store the image internally if the SD isn't available.

You must then keep track of the image's URI after downloading. Temporary images can simply be tracked with the app then deleted upon `onDestroy()`. Permanent image URIs should be stored via either [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), [`SQLite database`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db), or [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). A `ContentProvider` is preferred as it adds a layer of abstraction for how you want to store the image. It's usually backed by an SQLite database anyway, but other apps don't need to know that. It also allows other applications to easily access the image if you want (say, the Gallery for example). You can prevent access if you choose. `SharedPreferences` is easier to implement if you only have a few images. It's least recommended though.